# Компиляция файла .apk

Tags: android

Программа не компилируется, из-за того, что весит около 60 мб.

```
Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

В программе swf файлы. Загрузить их отдельно? Если да, то как это автоматизировать, чтобы пользователю не пришлось вручную в некую папку копировать данные файлы?

Или есть другие решения данной проблемы?

Comment: А Вам кто сказал, что дело в весе программы? Это бред полнейший, он же вам говорит - за деталями в логкат, там более подробное описание проблемы.

Comment: у гугла есть ограничение на 50Мб на apk.

Comment: флэшки убираю, и программа компилируется.

Answer (score 5):

Ох ох ох. 60мб с флешем... это тихий ужас. Это очень плохой подход. Но если уж решили, тогда следует использовать специальное расширение [expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). Оно позволяет подгружать файлы до 2 гигабайт. Я думаю, что этого на какое то время хватит.

Comment: У меня одного ссылка рекурсивная?

Comment: Какой подход хороший?

Comment: ссылку исправил. Что то подглючивает последним временем вставка ссылок на хешкоде.